# Isomorphic objects have the same dimension (pivotal categories)

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

I want to prove that if two objects $X,Y$ in a pivotal category $\mathcal{C}$ are isomorphic, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension, i.e.,
$$
\mathrm{dim}(X) = \mathrm{Tr}^{L}(\mathrm{id}_{X}) =  \mathrm{Tr}^{L}(\mathrm{id}_{Y}) = \mathrm{dim}(Y),$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}^{L}$ is the left quantum trace (see Tensor Categories-EGNO Ch 4.7). Hence, I want to show that the following diagram, corresponding to the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$, commutes:

[image]

Here $f\colon X \to Y$ is an isomorphism and $f^{\ast-1}$ is the dual morphism of $f^{-1}$.

I was able to show that the inner square commutes, but I am having trouble showing that the outer triangles commute. I tried taking the explicit form of $(f^{-1})^{\ast}$ but I don't get that the composition with $\mathrm{coev}_{X}$ should be $\mathrm{coev}_{Y}$. I would appreciate a hint for this last part.

Comment: I have not thought all the way through the problem but I suspect you want to use uniqueness of dual objects (Proposition 2.10.5 in EGNO).

Comment: Cross-posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877964/isomorphic-objects-have-the-same-dimension-pivotal-categories There is also an answer there.